# Can't Save File With rn-fetch-blob in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can't save file with rn-fetch-blob. I am picking image with react-native-image-crop-picker and saving cropped image with `cp()` method. It logs "Image saved at: /data/user/0/com.cropimage/files/1698007097111.jpg". But on the device I can't see saved image. I am added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

```
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

export default function App() {
  const saveLocalImage = (localImagePath: string, destinationPath: string) => {
    RNFetchBlob.fs
      .cp(localImagePath, destinationPath)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Image saved at:', destinationPath);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error saving image:', error);
      });
  };

  function pickImage() {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      cropping: true,
      freeStyleCropEnabled: true,
    }).then(image => {
      const sourceUri = image.path;
      const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
      const destinationPath = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir}/${timestamp}.jpg`;
      saveLocalImage(sourceUri, destinationPath);
    });
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        onPress={pickImage}
        title="Pick image"
        color="#841584"
        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the saveToCameraRoll method instead of RNFetchBlob

```
 CameraRoll.save(URL)
    .then(alert('Done', 'image download successfully')) 
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

[documentation link](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll#permissions)